# How to find the point estimate for a question with given mean and s.d.

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to go through a question and I am rather confused because after I compare the question to lecture slides, it seems to me that the answer has already been given but I assume that isn't the case.  So here is the question:

> A manager of Target Square Mall wants to estimate the population mean amount spent per year shopping visit by all customers.  A sample of 49
>   customers reveals the mean amount of 89.65 dollars with a standard
>   deviation of 23.50 dollars.
>
> a) What is the point estimate for the average amount spent per visit
>   by all customers at the mall?

Isn't the answer 89.65 already?  Because all my slides show the mean of their examples as the point estimate.

Comment: Yes - that's correct. I notice you've only got part (a) typed out. Perhaps the other parts get more involved?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I wanted to do the rest on my own.  Thank you very much, sir.